# Ubuntu 14.04 lts and Nvidia 9800GT

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, temperature

I recently aquired a new GeForce 9800GT GPU and an additional monitor for my desktop. I put it into my ubuntu x64 system, and installed the new drivers, initially from nvidia, then from the apt-get directory itself.

I'm using nvidia-340 and the expected dependencies on 14.04. I had 12.04, but upgraded to 14.04 hoping something would be better.

The GPU temperature gets HOT. I am talking 100C+. Initially, the temps after startup were so high during dual-monitor idling I assumed the sensors was broken (dumb, I know), but after opening up the case, I realized I could easily boil water on the GPU.

Since then, I've taken the card apart, reapplied thermal paste, and blasted every bit of dirt out of the fan. I have 3 fans in the case, 1 on the GPU, 1 on the CPU, 1 on the power supply, all functioning and running comfortably without blockage. There's no overclocking of any kind occurring. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the drivers, many different fixes, though I have not cataloged them.

I have tried bumblebee and removal/reinstallation of fglrx which removes/conflicts with nvidia-340. I have also tried versions nvidia-330 and nvidia-317 from apt-get. My desktop uses an AMD processor,  and many of these threads are about laptops and Intel processors.

However, temperatures upon a single monitor climb about 1 degree every 15 seconds, without any sort of upper ceiling I want to discover at all.